# Как вбить каптчу на сайт с другого сайта?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, я хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при изменении капчи на другом сайте она менялась и у меня на сайта?

Допустим, если, например, много страниц (любому будет лень каждую создавать) я хочу скопировать на свой сайт, чтобы при переходе на страницу определённого сайта `php` менял указанные "фразы" на мои, и удалял лишнее?

Answer (score 1):

Насчет капчи: если капча закрывает отправку данных на ваш сайт, то с другого ее не взять. Если на тот сайт, на который и уйдут данные, то как есть, так и берите ее. Насчет своего дизайна и чужих строчек или ссылок - учитесь кодить и парсить, раз уж вам так лень самому что-то делать свое.

Comment: Если бы капчу можно было вычислить, то сами посудите, зачем она нужна тогда??? Капча на один раз. Просто давайте ее тоже заполнять человеку, если хотите через свой сайт делать сервис отправки. А если хотите автоматом отправлять, то делайте модуль распознавания, если, конечно, сможете.

Comment: Там генерится капча с гугла. Если разберетесь, как она распознается со стороннего ресурса, то сможете сами распознавать ее.

Answer (score 0):

Может для капчи iframe использовать. )) Я что-то похожее делал на одном ресурсе, - делал панель авторизации с другим сайтом. Форма регистрации и дизайн был мой, а при логине пользователя данные отправлялись на сайт-партер и в ифрейме открывались уже нужные странички.